# Replacing "le musée" with a pronom in the sentence: " nous allons visiter le musée"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

There's this one question in my textbook, asking us to replace "le musée" with a pronoun, in this sentence:
"Nous allons visiter le musée"

The class is torn between the following answers:
"Nous allons le visiter"
And 
"Nous allons y visiter"

Which one is right , and why? I personally say the first one is right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Nous allons le visiter* is correct. *Le musée* is a direct object, it is a masculine noun, therefore *le* is the right pronoun to replace it.

*Y* would be ok if it were to replace a place complement, which is not the case in the sentence.

Compare with this one:

> Nous allons visiter l'exposition Picasso au musée.

Then "au musée" is a place complement and can be replaced by "y":

> Nous allons y visiter l'exposition Picasso.

Answer (score 3):

**Y** may retain its original meaning as an *adverb*, with the sense of *there* but its position is always of an *object* pronoun.

> Sachant que vous **y** seriez. Knowing that you would be **there**.
>
> Paul **y** a été envoyé. Paul was sent **there**.

As a pronoun, **y** represents a thing or things in the *Dative* or governed by the prepositions **à, en, dans**. Hence:

> On entendait les ordres, mais on n'y obéissait (i.e. les ordres) plus. (obéir à qqch)
>
> La maison n'était pas loin. Elle y a couru.
>
> Je n'ai pas confiance en ces choses. Je n'y ai aucune confiance.
>
> Il pensait à sa thèse. Il y pensait sans cesse.
>
> Il est impossible de pénétrer dans le château. Il est impossible d'y
>   pénétrer.

**Y** may be used **impersonally**, referring to a **clause** or **idea**.

> S'il gardait le silence, c'est qu'il y était obligé. (Musset)

**EDIT** Initially, I haven't answered directly your question. So I add this as an "appendix".

**Thus in your case:**

> "Nous allons visiter le musée" => Nous allons le visiter.

Le replaces here le musée.

On the contrary,

> Nous sommes au musée (à+le) => Nous y sommes (meaning we are there).

For y to replace a noun, the noun must come with a preposition (au musée here).

Similarly,

> Nous irons au musée. => Nous y irons.

References:

1. H. Ferrar: A French Reference Grammar, p. 202.
2. M. Offold: A Student Grammar of French, p. 184.

**EDIT 2** The expression Je n'y confiance (où y remplace en) is not encountered anymore in French. See the discussion here [y et avoir confiance en](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29587/avoir-confiance-en-p%C3%A9n%C3%A9trer-dans-plus-nom-et-le-pronom-y)

Comment: Nice, but you haven't spelled out the implication for this question.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Certainly! I add sth in order to reply to the question directly.

Comment: Merci ! Upvoté.

Comment: Je te remercie également !

Comment: "Je n'y ai aucune confiance" sounds very odd to my native ears, but I must admit I can't explain why. I would rather say "je n'ai aucune confiance en elles". Maybe because the "en" does not inidcate a direction or a location here ? Similarly, for eg "j'ai confiance en la médecine", I would say "j'ai confiance en elle", not "j'y ai confiance".

Comment: @Greg C'est un exemple trouvé dans le livre de H. Ferrar (Ref. 1). Le livre est un peu archaïque (2e édition 1967). Donc, les exemples ne sont pas assez courants peut-être. L'autre livre, qui est récent, (ref 2) ne donne pas un tel exemple. Je vous remercie pour votre commentaire.

Comment: Plus j'y pense, plus je suis convaincu que "y" ne peut remplacer un nom introduit par la préposition "en" que s'il s'agit d'un complément de lieu. Comparez: "j'habite en France: j'y habite" et "j'ai confiance en la France: j'ai confiance en elle".

Comment: @Greg Je viens de poser une nouvelle question ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29587/avoir-confiance-en-et-pronoun-y  Si tu veux, on peut y continuer la discussion. Ce faisant le problématique va attirer plus d'attention.

Comment: @dimitris-After having verified a sentence I modified earlier (For y to replace a noun, the noun must ...) I  wondered whether what had been meant would not be put more pertinently as  "For "y" to replace a noun the verb to which this noun is a complement has to be constructed with a preposition."?