# Avoir confiance en, pénétrer dans plus nom et le pronom y

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, prépositions, y

C'est une question qui concerne ma réponse à la question intitulée : 
[Replacing “le musée” with a pronom in the sentence: “ nous allons visiter le musée”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29570/replacing-le-mus%C3%A9e-with-a-pronom-in-the-sentence-nous-allons-visiter-le-mus/29577#29577).

Selon le livre "*A French Reference Grammar, H. Ferrar*, p. 202. *(Oxford University Press, 2nd Edition, 1967)*" le pronom **y** peut remplacer des choses introduites par **à**, **en** et **dans**.

Ainsi donnent-ils les exemples suivants :

> Il y pensait sans cesse (penser à).
>
> Je n'y ai aucune confiance (avoir confiance en).
>
> Le château existe, mais il est impossible d'y pénétrer (pénétrer
>   dans).

Un autre livre de grammaire que j'utilise (*A Student Grammar of French*, M. Offold, p. 184. *Cambridge University Press*, 2006) ne donne que des exemples dans lesquels *y* remplace *à + nom* et ne parle pas de *dans* et *en*.

Alors, en français courant, peut-on remplacer *en + nom* / *dans + nom* par *y* ou le premier livre donne-t-il des exemples un peu archaïques, voire erronés ?

Comment: Merci pour les corrections !

Comment: Je n'y ai aucune confiance ne se dit pas (ou plus), mais je n'ai aucune confiance (en cela, ...)

Comment: Voici un cas (vieux quand même:-)!). https://books.google.fr/books?id=OGNJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA888&dq=Je+n%27y+ai+confiance&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg-tzwkpraAhVJCMAKHSRoBK8Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Je%20n'y%20ai%20confiance&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La première phrase me laisse perplexe :

> Je n'y ai aucune confiance (avoir confiance en).

Google books n'en trouve qu'une poignée d'occurrences, souvent dans des textes traduits, et essentiellement durant une période située entre 1830 et 1940.

[image]

Aujourd'hui, personne n'utiliserait cette tournure. Des formes courantes sont :

> Je ne leur fais aucune confiance.
>
> Je n'ai aucune confiance en eux/elles.

La deuxième phrase est au contraire tout a fait habituelle :

> Le château existe, mais il est impossible d'y pénétrer (pénétrer dans).

Comment: Merci pour la réponse ! Moi je ne trouve que deux ou trois occurrences. Voici une : https://books.google.fr/books?id=iVY-AAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA252&dq=Je+n%27y+ai+confiance&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGudO7k5raAhUCOsAKHcQ2DAk4ChDoAQg_MAM#v=onepage&q=Je%20n'y%20ai%20confiance&f=false C'est de 1830. Il me paraît que c'est désuet. C'est intéressant de savoir quand cette tournure est devenue désuète. Quand le livre dont je parle n'est pas assez vieux (1967).

Comment: C'est bon ! Merci encore pour la réponse actualisée.

Answer (score 1):

*Y* peut être soit pronom locatif, soit pronom object indirect. Dans le premier cas, il est utilisé pour faire référence au lieu ou à la destination d'une action. Dans le second cas, il est imposé par la valence verbale.

"J'y conduis souvent" peut vouloir dire aussi bien "Je conduis souvent à la mer" que "Je conduis souvent sur le circuit", "Je conduis souvent jusque chez toi" ou "Je conduis souvent dans la forêt". Le pronom peut correspondre à n'importe quel complément locatif, quelle que soit la préposition qui le régit.

Dans son usage intrinsèque comme pronom objet, par contre, *y* ne peut faire référence qu'à un complément objet indirect régi par les prépositions *à* ou, dans de très rares cas (seul *croire* me vient à l'esprit), *en/dans*.