# Replace the object which comes after "dans" with a personal pronoun

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

> Je suis dans le cinéma.
>   Je suis dans la classe.
>   Je suis sur le trottoir.

Is there anyway I can replace the objects after "dans" or "sur". I tried to google it but failed to get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the pronoun *y*.

> Je suis dans le cinéma.
>
> Je suis dans la classe.
>
> Je suis sur le trottoir.
>
> =>J'y suis.

See here for instance:

https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-grammar/how-to-use-the-pronoun-y-in-french

> 1 – The French Pronoun Y Replaces A PLACE. A place is introduced by a
> preposition of place which can be “à” but also “sur, sous, en, au,
> aux…”:
>
> Je vais à Paris = j’y vais
>
> Je vais en France = j’y vais
>
> Je vais au
> Japon = j’y vais

**Additional staff**

Y may retain its original meaning as an adverb, with the sense of there but its position is always of an object pronoun.

> Sachant que vous y seriez. Knowing that you would be there.
>
> Paul y a été envoyé. Paul was sent there.

As a pronoun, y represents a thing or things in the Dative or governed by the prepositions à, en, dans. Hence:

> On entendait les ordres, mais on n'y obéissait (i.e. les ordres) plus. (obéir à qqch)
>
> La maison n'était pas loin. Elle y a couru.
>
> Il pensait à sa thèse. Il y pensait sans cesse.
>
> Il est impossible de pénétrer dans le château. Il est impossible d'y pénétrer.

Y may be used impersonally, referring to a clause or idea.

S'il gardait le silence, c'est qu'il y était obligé. (Musset)

Watch the difference:

> "Nous allons visiter le musée" => Nous allons le visiter.

Le replaces here le musée.

On the contrary,

> Nous sommes au musée (à+le) => Nous y sommes (meaning we are there).

For y to replace a noun, the noun must come with a preposition (au musée here).

Similarly,

> Nous irons au musée. => Nous y irons.

References:

H. Ferrar: A French Reference Grammar, p. 202.

M. Offold: A Student Grammar of French, p. 184.

See also the threads:

[Replacing "le musée" with a pronom in the sentence: " nous allons visiter le musée"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29570/replacing-le-mus%C3%A9e-with-a-pronom-in-the-sentence-nous-allons-visiter-le-mus)

[Avoir confiance en, pénétrer dans plus nom et le pronom y](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29587/avoir-confiance-en-p%C3%A9n%C3%A9trer-dans-plus-nom-et-le-pronom-y)

Comment: But won't it be unclear where exactly am I? Whether i am in or on. like in English when we say i am under or on it

Comment: There is no (regular) way to be *sur le cinéma* or *dans le trottoir* so this detail is not necessary.

Comment: But a cat for instance can be on or under the table

Comment: @Manar: When it's really necessary to the understanding, you can add an adverb as in: *le chat s'y est mis dessus/dessous/dedans/à coté*. But then, *y* is not strictly necessary in many such cases.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: Really thank you! That is what I was really asking and searching Google for.

Comment: @Manar It is actually not really necessary. When you say *Le chat s'y est mis*, the place you are referring to (the *antécédent*) is already known. If you want to restate it, you can use what Stephane suggested, although that should include a colon: *Le chat s'y est mis, dessous* which means *Le chat s'est mis dessous*.

Comment: @jiliagre So do you want to say that using it the way Stephane suggested could sound abit unnatural in french in contrary to English where one would usually say for instance : _How do you stand that little shower? I could barely get under it._ rather than, _How do you stand that little shower? I could barely get below._ by the way I am no way a native, I just think that the first sentence sounds more natural than the second

Comment: @Manar Using your example, the question : *Comment tu la trouves, cette petite douche ?* One might answer : *J'y tiens à peine* (I barely fit there) or *Je tiens à peine dessous* (I barely fit under it) but *J'y tiens à peine dessous* (I barely fit there under it) is breaking formal French grammar.

Comment: So dedans/dessus and others adv like them which usually come at the end of the sentence literally mean "under/above _*it*_ "?because if not then i guess the translation is _I barely fit under there._

Comment: @Manar *Dedans* means inside and *dessus* means *above*. They are standalone, you can't say *je suis dedans la douche* or *je suis dessus le trottoir*, that should be *je suis dans la douche* and *je suis sur le trottoir*.

Comment: @jiliagre I'm sorry. I know I ask alot of questions but just one last thing. Why is _Le chat s'y est mis, dessous_ is right ,even tho as you said it would be better written without the Y, while _J'y tiens à peine dessous_ is grammatically wrong?

Comment: Hi, I've improved my French a bit. And I've come to this conclusion which I wanted to share here with you to know if it's right or wrong before actually making it as an answer for this question. What I came to realise is in French ,unlike English, dessous/dessus actually means: under/on **sth** or under/on **it** or at least that's how it's translated, for example: _C'est écrit dessus_ is translated as : _It's written on **it** ._ However, sth like dessus can also be translated as underneath (with no _it_ ) as in: _Mets ton sac dessous_ = _Put your bag underneath._

Comment: And of course  there's **Y/là** meaning _there_ but what I was waiting to hear or to be answered with was an equivalent to *it*. But unfortunately I wasn't accurate enough about what it is I was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

As Dimitris answered, you can always use *y* to refer to a location:

> *Je suis dans le cinéma.*
> *Je suis dans la classe.*
> *Je suis sur le trottoir.*
>
> *J'y suis.* (I'm there)

If you want to provide more details :

> *Je suis dedans* (I'm inside) (*cinema, classe*)
>
> *Je suis dessus* (I'm on the top of it) (*trottoir*)

...